# Why does SwiftUI opacity animation fail in Gesture's onEnded method?

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui, opacity

As shown in the gif below, the second tap on the purple rectangle does not trigger the animation for the blue rectangle to fade in. Is this a Bug or an obscure Feature?

Thanks for your kind reply!

[trying to toggle the opacity of the big blue rectangle with animation (sorry, not enough reputation to post images)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teMq3.gif)

```swift
struct FadeTestView: View {
  @State var fade: Bool = false
  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      Rectangle().fill(.blue).frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
        .opacity(fade ? 0 : 1)
      
      Button(action: {
        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2)){ fade.toggle() }
      }){
        Circle().fill(.yellow).frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
      }
      
      Rectangle().fill(.purple).frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
        .gesture(TapGesture().onEnded{
          withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2)){ fade.toggle() }
        })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use linear if its just for change opacity

```
struct FadeTestView: View {
@State var fade: Bool = false
var body: some View {
VStack{
  Rectangle().fill(.blue).frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment:       .center)
    
    .opacity(fade ? 0 : 1)
  
  Button(action: {
      withAnimation(.linear(duration: 2)){ fade.toggle() }
  }){
    Circle().fill(.yellow).frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
  }
  
  Rectangle().fill(.purple).frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
        .onTapGesture() {
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 2)){
                fade.toggle()
            }
        }
       
}
}

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug with `.opacity`. The work around seems to simply be not changing all of the way to 0.

```
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.blue)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            .opacity(fade ? 0.01 : 1)
```

Any lower on `.opacity` gets treated like 0, but .01 is effectively transparent.